# create-react-app - can't use npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have never used react in a standalone project, always with Rails.
I wanted to `create-react-app` today and so I ran `create-react-app myapp`.

`npm start` and everything went smoothly until I wanted to add some npm packages, let's say `flow-bin`:

When I run `npm install --save-dev flow-bin` it says this:

```
npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /mypath/myapp/node_modules/espree/node_modules/.bin/acorn as it wasn't installed by /mypath/myapp/node_modules/espree/node_modules/acorn
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
+ flow-bin@0.47.0
added 1 package and removed 1096 packages in 15.55s
```

And when I try to run `npm start` there are also some errors. 
Is this a bug? Why is `npm install` removing my packages?

Versions:

1. NPM - 5.0.3
2. Node - 7.10.0
3. create-react-app - 1.3.1

Comment: what is the error log?

Comment: Seems like this is a bug connected with NPM version, as I found an open issue on their github